# Drone CI get and use build metadata

Tags: drone.io

I'm using Drone CI (0.7) in a self-hosted system. It's hooked up to GitLab and my private registry and working great!

However, I'd like to do more with the `.drone.yml` file. Especially when publishing images to the registry.

The docs show how to do [substitution](http://docs.drone.io/substitution/), but doesn't explain how those variables are set. Below is an example from the docs:

```
pipeline:
  docker:
    image: plugins/docker
+   tags: ${DRONE_TAG}
```

This is exactly what I'd like to do. Create a git tag on the repo (on the release branch) and have that tag become the tag for my Docker image.

I've tried `git tag -a v1.0 -m "Initial release"` then `git push origin v1.0`. The Drone CI build kicks off as I've set the `Tag Hooks` for the repository, but when the build completes, and publishes the image to the registry, the tag is set to `latest`. This also happens when pushing a regular code change commit.

Is this something that needs to be done with the CLI, or am I missing something in my `.drone.yml` file (posted below)? It *looks* like an environment variable I would need to set, but that seems strange to have to set that (I'm assuming) just before committing code to start a build...

Any and all help is appreciated!

```
pipeline:
  build:
    image: node:latest
    commands:
      - npm install
      - npm test
  docker:
    image: plugins/docker
    repo: private.registry.com/tester
    registry: private.registry.com
    secrets: [ docker_username, docker_password ]
    tags: ${DRONE_TAG}
    when:
      branch: release
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your `docker` step is only being triggered when you push a new commit to the branch `release`, you should use the tag event.

Yo should have some similar configuration

```
tags:
  - latest
  - ${DRONE_TAG##v}
when:
  event: tag
```

note ${DRONE_TAG##v} will strip the prefix `v`, since you are naming your tag `v1.0` drone will parse this into

```
tags:
  - latest
  - 1.0
when:
  event: tag
```

Comment: Cool! But can anyone can explain why `##v` can strip the prefix?

Comment: @SiruiZhuang see docs here http://docs.drone.io/substitution/, actually it can be applied for any env variables and it will depend for your particular use case

Comment: @jhernandez Thank you!